# Upgraded from 21.04 to 22.04 failure: now have flashing desktop icons. What should I do?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

My upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04 failed at a certain point said, something like "UDev cannot be installed". I did a recovery and got to the desktop finally, but now the desktop icons  blink / flash.  Constantly appear then disappear.

Here's a video: https://youtube.com/shorts/KT-jLltAYB0?feature=share

Not sure what I should do next in an attempt to resolve this.

Also my Remmina toolbar now looks like the following:

[image: remmina toolbar]

**Rebooted**

Rebooted and got desktop, saw that I could try a Partial Update.  Tried it and saw the following:

[image: udev]

Comment: There isn't and never was an upgrade path from 21.04 to 22.04. It would have to be 21.04 > 21.10 then 22.04 (21.04 NOT an LTS). So, backup and install from scratch 22.04.

Comment: I already backed up so that is good.  It is interesting that the Software Updater itself offered 22.04 to me.  I didn't know there wasn't an upgrade path.  I'm a bit confused on that part.  Oh well

Comment: There's an upgrade path between LTS releases like from 20.04 to 22.04. If the software updater offered 22.04 there you weren't running 21.04, it was either 20.04 or 21.10. the latter being EoL that wasn't recommended either.

Comment: About blinking desktop icons, for what it's worth, I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu MATE 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish). The file manager for the MATE desktop - Caja - has been crashing a lot.  The problem is that any time I open a folder that contains a PDF, a JPG or a PNG file, that folder instantly disappears.  So I opened a PDF from the command-line, and suddenly the icons on my desktop started to blink on and off.  I only did that once & I'm not inclined to try again, but just to say that this was another thing that caused the desktop icons to blink. I wonder if it signals something specific.